# My nav is displaying below my logo, need it to the right

Tags: html, css, nav

Have been trying to code a small website design, and have been caught up on this issue for a while.  My nav area is below my example logo, and I need it to the right, however, I cannot get it there.  I've tried floating, absolute positioning, and using col but I'm either doing it wrong or it's not working.

My HTML Code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- Logo, Search Bar, Categories, and User Profile -->
        <a href="index.html"> <img height="64px" width="313px" id="logopic" src="images/logoeg.png"> </a> <!-- LogoPic linking to HomePage -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Home |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Browse |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Categories |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Rising</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

My CSS Code:

```
header{
    background-color: #00829F;
    font-family: system-ui;
    color: white;
    font-size: 34px;
}
#logopic{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
    html, body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    display: inline;
}
a:link{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[A picture of my page, showcasing the issue at hand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTlgK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `position:fixed` ? Try this on your nav. it fixes the nav to the right edge and 8 px from top.

```
position:fixed;
right:0px;
top: -8px;
```

Comment: This did the trick! Wanted it right by the logo, so I changed the right to a left and adjusted as needed, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. Consider accepting my answer since you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

give link an id and float it to the left. Then take .nav and float it right! Sometimes thinking you floated the correct tag can mix you up!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use flexbox in your project, adding these styles should do the trick. See also the included code pen link.

```
header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: middle;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

a, nav {
  align-self: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/shanedaugherty/pen/vpxNLq

Answer (score 0):

To float the logo container right you need to apply the float to the parent container. You also need to wrap the parent in a div container so you can clear the float before the navigation links.

```css
header{
    background-color: #00829F;
    font-family: system-ui;
    color: white;
    font-size: 34px;
}

.logoContainer{
  display:block;
  float:right;
}

.clear:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

#logopic{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
    html, body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li{
    display: inline;
}
a:link{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- Logo, Search Bar, Categories, and User Profile -->
        <div class="clear">
          <a class="logoContainer" href="index.html">
            <img height="64px" width="313px" id="logopic" src="http://via.placeholder.com/313x64">
          </a><!-- LogoPic linking to HomePage -->
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Home |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Browse |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Categories |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Rising</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex property to achieve this:

Make your header to flex. It will automatically align your logo and nav in single line.. To align logo vertically center you can use align-items to center.

```
header{
    background-color: #00829F;
    font-family: system-ui;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    font-size: 34px;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Check my Fiddle to get better idea: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep0594/9z9m9xk0/2/)

Justify-content will make your logo and nav to have spacing between them